# Ember binding model to template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having hard time to understand the different ways to bind models to templates in Ember and when use one or the others.

Following different tutorial my code should work but it doesn't.
cal.hbs

```
<div class="calendar">
    {{#each cal}}
        {{#if days_label.length}}
            {{days_label.[1]}}
        {{/if}}
        {{test}}
    {{/each}}

</div>
```

cal_model.js

```
WebCalendar.Cal = DS.Model.extend({
    today: DS.attr('date'),
    test: DS.attr('number'),
    days_label: DS.attr('array'),
    months_label: DS.attr('array'),
    days_per_month: DS.attr('array')

});


WebCalendar.Cal.FIXTURES = [{   
        id: 1,
        test: 2,
        today: new Date(),
        days_label: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

        months_label: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
                         'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
                         'October', 'November', 'December'],

        days_per_month: [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
}];
```

Router.js

```
WebCalendar.CalRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('cal');
    }
});
```

cal_controller.js

```
WebCalendar.CalController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    month: function(){
        var today = this.get('test');
        return today + 1;
    }.property('model'),

    monthCal: function(year, month){
        var today = this.store.find('cal', { today: new Date() });
        this.year = today.getFullYear();
        this.month = today.getMonth();
    },


    updateContent: function() { //doesn't work if is called arrangedContent
        return this.get('model').content;
    }.property('model')
});
```

For what I understood there are these ways to hook the model:
First

```
<div class="calendar">
    {{#each cal}}
        {{#if days_label.length}}
            {{days_label.[1]}}
        {{/if}}
        {{test}}
    {{/each}}

</div>
```

Second

```
<div class="calendar">
    {{#each cal in controller}}
        {{#if days_label.length}}
            {{days_label.[1]}}
        {{/if}}
        {{test}}
    {{/each}}

</div>
```

Third

```
<div class="calendar">
    {{#each item in arrangedContent}} //this work if I don't specify arrangedContent in my controller
        {{#if item.days_label.length}}//this doesn't work
            {{item.days_label.[1]}}//this doesn't work
        {{/if}}
        {{item.test}}// this works
    {{/each}}

</div>
```

What I want to understand and I can't find good explanation around is: what's the difference between those ways, when use what and what exactly is and does arrangedContent

Thank you very much for any explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrangedContent ,if Im not wrong , is an array generated by 
[EMBER.SORTABLEMIXIN CLASS](http://ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html) that is nowday implemented by default to [EMBER.ARRAYPROXY CLASS](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html) , so your arraycontrollers inherit the [arrangedcontent property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#property_arrangedContent).

What it really is , an array that is your controller's content , sorted by the properties you'll define in your controller ([sortProperties, sortAscending](http://ember-doc.com/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortProperties)).

So if I have a controller content(that is an array of objects that have the property name) , I can choose to sort them by the name property (sortProperties: ['name'] , thus rendering them in alphabetical order ascending (sortAscending: true).

The difference between your first and second question, is what is passed inside the loop as the current object.

In first you will call `{{days_label}}` to get the days_label that is equivalent as saying `this.days_label`.

In your second example though you can call `{{days_label}}`, but also call `cal.days_label` that in both cases is the same but it's needed if you were let's say go deeper inside an iteration, as:

> {{#each cal in controller}}
>
> ```
>    {{#if days_label.length}}
>        {{#each day in days_label}}
>            {{day.someProperty}}
>            {{days_label.someOtherProperty}}
>         {{/each}}
>
>    {{/if}}
>    {{test}}
> ```
>
> {{/each}}

In this example I could just do `{{#each controller}}` ,inside it  `{{#each days_label}}` and then do `{{someProperty}}` inside it , but then I wouldn't be able to do the same for `{{days_label.someOtherProperty}}` because `this` would have changed.

One more thing to consider (very usefull when you are using ember data), is the difference between the model and the content of the controller. 
The content is set inside route's [setupController (controller, model)](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) but can be overwritten.

### UPDATE

> Thank you again for your answer :) Right, the code is bit messy now but what i'm try to achieve now is very simple. With the model that I have, I want to display the current month. I try to take 'today' from my model, in my controller, do today.getMonth() and save as property(month), so i should be able to display in the hbs with {{month}}. –  Giorgia Sambrotta

What I would do then is move the logic from the controller inside the model.
Some basic things to understand about ember data is that calling `this.store.find('resourceName')`, makes a request to your api's resoure index route thus returning an array of objects.
This call will be triggered each time you access this route because ember is agnostic of whereas your records have been changed at your server.

So given that you get an array of objects that all have some sort of date in them and you just want to get their month from it , you can define a computed property inside your `WebCalendar.Cal` model.

#### Inside WebCalendar.Cal

```
  month: (function() {
    var today = this.get('today');
    //do something to get the value you want here
  }).property('today')
```

Another thing to consider is that since `months_label`, `days_label` and `days_per_month` are static arrays you really don't need to pass them in each record but instead move them inside your model too, as properties.

So now that we've moved logic to the model you can just call {{month}} inside itteration and this will give you the result of the model's computed property. Also if a cal record happens to change today  you will get that change imediately.

The only reason you wouldn't want to do it this way is if you wouldn't want this month property anywhere else except this specific controller.
In this case you would go

#### Inside WebCalendar.CalController

> ```
> setMonthToEachCal: function(){
>    this.get('content').forEach(function(cal) { 
>      today = cal.get('today');
>      //prepare the month value here and set it in month var
>      cal.set('month', month);
>    });
> }.observes('content.@each.today'),
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It help me to clarify some stuff! I took some time to read carefully and now I'm back with some additional questions:) 1_ knowing what arrangedContent is, why the third option doesn't work? When I should update arrangedContent? 2_If First and Second are both correct(at least at this level of deepness), why they donesn't work? 3_ Is it correct that i'm using a ArrayController? I can't understand if I'm using and Array or an Object, for what I understood, Cal is an Array with just one element inside. And in my controller I manipulate all its properties.

Comment: Oh, and another thing that is totally unclear from the ember guideline is: Is ok that i'm using a  this.store.find('cal'); or I should use setupController? Btw if I inspect, my CalController, i have the model in my content. But they are not displayed

Comment: In order to give you a clear answer, you have to expain what you are trying to achieve. I can't understand if you are trying to access an array of objects in this controller and then manipulate them , fetch just a single object (be it the first webcalendar) or fetch a specific webcalendar (lets say with id: 1).

Comment: Also try to inspect in your browser console what item is in your 3d example and what this is in your first and second example. This can be achieved by inserting a {{debugger}} inside the iteration (in hbs file). It will freeze the iteration and you can just type item in your browser's console to inspect it.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer :) Right, the code is bit messy now but what i'm try to achieve now is very simple. With the model that I have, I want to display the current month. I try to take 'today' from my model, in my controller, do today.getMonth() and save as property(month), so i should be able to display in the hbs with {{month}}.

Comment: Wooow that's an answer :) Ok everything start to have more sense now, for real. thank you very much. I will follow your suggestion, move them in model and make them property and try to keep this schema in mind for the next steps!

Comment: mhmm I follow your tips and super simplify things just to see where the error could be and it turn out that this.get('something') is undefined. Looking all examples and the guide, this is right. Do you have any idea why is undefined? Here is a codepen with the last code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjuLx?editors=101

Comment: I don't understand where you are refering when you say this.get('something'), I took a look at your code though. Seems like you had put the month computed property inside fixture and also you hadn't added the jquery library to your pen. Here's an update to it :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwuiz

Comment: Ahhh! I see! ok i was confusing model with Fixture for all the time!! Model right, in model! Thank you very much. All of these was really helpful, i can do just basic things but at least I really get there now! Thankss